# Questions regarding a code with recursive methods

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

I have some questions about this code

```
public static String reverseString( String s )
{
  if ( s.length() == 0 )
    return "";

  String firstChar = s.substring( 0, 1 );
  String reverseRest = reverseString( s.substring( 1 ) );

  String result = reverseRest + firstChar;

  return result;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
  String a = "The sky's the limit!";
  System.out.println( reverseString( a ) );
}
```

Question 1: How exactly does the terminating circumstances work? How will s.length ever equal 0?

Question 2: Why does the code need to have the "firstChar" to be able to reverse the string? Why doesn't the code work when reverseString takes in substring of 0 and not have to add the first character?

Comment: Sorry it should be mentioned in that for the first question, the code does not work if the terminating circumstance is not there, why is it necessary when it seems that the code would work finely without it?

Comment: Without the terminating condition, it will eventually be taking a substring of an empty string and crashing.

Comment: @Tran- so you mean to say that code works fine without this condition, `if ( s.length() == 0 ) return ""; ` ? Did you actually ran it without this condition?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Sure I understand the basic premises of the code but it would really help my understanding if I also grasped parts the "what-if" parts of the code.

Comment: @SabirKhan yes I did try to run it with the removal of that part and I got "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1 

at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963) 

at TC1.reverseString(TC1.java:8) "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question 1: How exactly does the terminating circumstances work? How
>   will s.length ever equal 0?

If you read [the docs on `String.substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-), then you'll understand that it returns the substring starting with the specified character and extending all the way to the end. Since you specify the starting character 1, and the characters are numbered starting with 0, `substring(1)` essentially means "starting with the second character". This way, the string length decreases by exactly one character for the nested call. Of course it will reach 0 eventually! It will reach 0 when you take `substring(1)` from a string of length 1 because for such a string "starting with the second character" means an empty substring.

> Question 2: Why does the code need to have the "firstChar" to be able
>   to reverse the string? Why doesn't the code work when reverseString
>   takes in substring of 0 and not have to add the first character?

Well, that's what recursion is all about. If you take the first character, reverse the rest of the string and then append that character to the *end* of the reversed rest-of-the-string, what will you get if not the reversed string?

Or, if you want to be rigorous, which is a honorable thing, then let's do it the right way. Let's first prove that this function reverses string of length 0 properly.

The reversed empty string is the empty string itself. Since the code returns an empty string explicitly when the input string is empty (by the way, better replace `length() == 0` with `isEmpty()` for clarity), this proves that the function works for 0-length strings. That wasn't that hard, was it?

Now let's prove that if the function works for a string of length `i` (`i >= 0`), then it will also work for a string of length `i + 1`. Suppose `s.length() == i + 1`. We take the first character and then call `reverseString( s.substring( 1 ) )`. The argument to this call is a string of length `i` because it's exactly one character shorter than `s`. Since we've assumed that our function works perfectly for strings of length `i`, the result is the properly reversed substring of our string starting with character 1 (the second). We then append to this string the first character of `s`, thus making the properly reversed `s` of length `i + 1`.

We've proven that it works for length `0`, so from our second proof it follows that it must also work fine for length `1`. But from that it follows that it works for length `2` too. And so on, and so on... That's how you prove that the recursive functions work.

Now what happens if you don't add the first character. Assuming the function worked perfectly for a shorter string (`substring(1)`), you end up with a string one character shorter. A string one character shorter will obviously *not* be the reverse of the original, so that proves that this function can't possibly work if you just reverse `substring(1)` without appending anything to the result.

What will happen if you pass `substring(0)` in the recursive call? That's another interesting question. In the second part of our proof we assumed that the function works for shorter strings. In this case, `substring(0)` is not a shorter string. In fact, it's the original string itself, so passing `substring(0)` is equivalent to just passing `s`. So our proof doesn't exactly work any more. Moreover, since we're making an identical call, it will continue to call itself again and again and again, until you get a `StackOverflowError` when recursion becomes too deep.

So the whole idea is based on breaking the task at hand into smaller pieces, and `substring(0)` is not a smaller piece. One another interesting task would be to divide the string in two halfs instead of just chopping off one character and then return `reverseString(right) + reverseString(left)`. I'd suggest you try to do this (be careful with odd/even lengths), see if it works, and prove how it works.